# where does express.js store variable value?

Tags: node.js

I found some snippets from express.js tutorials as following.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

var names = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.render('index.jade', { names : names });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){

names.push(req.body.name);
res.redirect('/'); 
});

app.listen('3000',function(){

   console.log('start to listen port:3000');
})
```

**index.jade**

```
h1 Names

ul
    for name in names
        li=name

hr
h1 Add Name
form(method='POST')
    input(name='name')
    button Submit
```

As I submit some names,the names variable keeps show on the page!

Even I start a new browser and check the root page, the names variable is still exist!!!!

How does it work?

For my knowledge, HTTP is stateless. I dont think PHP could do something like this since it has been redirect, how the heck did the root page know the names variable without saving into session or cookies?

And I dont think the names variable is session or cookie in the above code.

Could someone give me some hint?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing them into `names`, which is a variable declared in the parent scope and thus accessible by *all* requests. So it's not per-session or per-request, it's per-life of the server process.

Comment: Thanks,so does it mean if multiple users submit the names, all users can see the whole bunch of list?

Comment: @wilsonLiu - yes, that is the consequence of using a top level variable like you are using - that variable is used by all requests from all users.  If you want to store things on behalf of a single user, then it takes more work to identify the user and store stuff particularly for them.  There are session modules that help you do that.